# AAD auth to Azure SQL Database management API with multiple tenants

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory

I need to interact with Azure SQL servers on two different tenants (tenant_a, tenant_b) using Python and authenticating with my own active directory credentials.

To be clear, I'm not trying to query the databases. I need to modify settings in the SQL servers via the Azure SQL Database management API. And I have to use my own AAD credentials. I understand there may be better options but those are not available to me.

I've been trying to use the Azure Python SDK libraries, and can create a SqlManagementClient instance and interact with the SQL server for the default tenant (tenant_a) ok, but if I try to create a client for tenant_b in the same way, I get the error message `AzureCliCredential.get_token failed: Please run 'az login' to set up an account`

```py
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.sql import SqlManagementClient

cred = AzureCliCredential(tenant_id)
sqlsvr_client = SqlManagementClient(cred, subscription_id)
```

Running `az account tenant list` in the terminal returns both tenant IDs

```json
[
  {
    "id": "/tenants/<tenant_a_id>",
    "tenantId": "<tenant_a_id>"
  },
  {
    "id": "/tenants/<tenant_b_id>",
    "tenantId": "<tenant_b_id>"
  }
]
```

but running `az account list` only shows subscriptions under tenant_a.

It seems like the CLI can only be logged into one tenant at a time, even though it can see both tenant ids. However, I can connect to the Azure SQL databases on both tenants with AAD auth using sqlalchemy without needing to log in/out multiple times by passing the required tenant id to `AzureCliCredential()` then getting a token from the credential for the database scope and using that to build a connection string in each case. That enables me to interact with databases on different servers in the same code without having to log into different accounts.

```py
tenants = {'tenant_a': <tenant_a_id>, 'tenant_b':<tenant_b_id>}
db_engines = {}
for k, v in tenants.items():
    cred = AzureCliCredential(tenant_id=v)
    db_token = cred.get_token('https://database.windows.net/')
    
    # process the token...
    # build the conn string...
    # create the sqlalchemy engine...
    
    db_engines[k] = engine
```

I want to be able to do something similar for the SQL Database management API i.e., have a client for each SQL server without having to log into different accounts in the CLI.

Is there any way to do this using the `azure.identity` library to create a client per tenant? If not, is there some other approach, perhaps interacting with the API more directly and passing a token?